# Java Swing text is messed up inside Text Area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jtextarea

I've formatted the result of a query to MySql's style, with all the +----+.

In eclipse, the string looks just as I want, but in my GUI, it is messed up:
[image]

Any idea how can I make the text inside the JTextArea the same as inside eclipse?

Comment: Use a monospaced font.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747860/style-a-jtextpane-to-have-console-like-formatting

Comment: Use a `JTable` **instead of** the text area..

Comment: Use a fixed-width font. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279781/getting-jtextarea-to-display-fixed-width-font-without-antialiasing

Comment: JTable is nice option, but the problem is not all queries return tables... just the ones which returns ResultSet. I can also get an integer or an exception.

Regarding the email, they're fake, you're welcome to use them :)

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @Neal4114 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) *"JTable is nice option, but the problem is not all queries return tables..."* Then the solution is a `CardLayout` with a `JTable` in one card and component(s) better suited to the output received in other card(s).

Answer (score 3):

The text is not messed up, it's just using a non-monospaced font so not all characters have the same width.

Just do this to your TextArea:

```
textArea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: *"Just do this to your TextArea:"* 1) As stated in the question, that is a `JTextArea` 2) `new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12)` would better be `new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12)` for cross-platform reliability & compile time checking. 3) There is a better solution to this, as expressed in my comment..

Comment: Calm down a little. This solution is fine and will solve the problem. It will work in any OS I know of. A JTable is NOT a better solution as the question is not how to make a Table but how to make the text look like in Eclipse.

Comment: why? This is the right solution!!! I said TextArea, but of course JTextArea has a setFont() method.

Comment: *"..is not how to make a Table but how to make the text look like in Eclipse."*  So if the question was *"how do I shoot myself in the foot?"* you would provide instructions?  See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) (yes).

Comment: Printing a Table as text is not the same as shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Guys, read what I answered to Andrew, what about integer / exception results? Not all results are tables. if you have any idea, I'm glad to hear...

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but @AndrewThompson is correct; as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26090878/230513), `Font.MONOSPACED` will elicit the platform's preferred fixed-width font for variations in weight, slope & locale. Renato: Because formatting with spaces is fragile at best, use the strategy pattern, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31764798/230513), to select the correct renderer; `JTable` will avoid having to design your own renderer selection scheme.